# Assign value to variable inside Function

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a function as stated below. But, I'm not sure on how to assign the values roles from database in the variable. Because I need the values roles' to decide either the user is admin or not. Velow is my code.

```
function find_user_by_username(string $username){
    //find users in the database acourding to Input
    $sql = 'SELECT username, password, roles from users WHERE username=:username';
    $statement = dbConnect()->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindValue(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->execute();
    
    return $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Kindly advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best method is to save the required information in the session when logging in.

Or use the following code:

```
$result = find_user_by_username($username) ;
if ($result["roles"] == 'admin'){}
```

Comment: What, if the username was not found? Then result has no key `roles`.

Comment: The programmer completes the suggested codes. you can use this code : `if(isset($result["roles"]))`
Or many other ways